# issue with opening main.xml in android and eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have the following error when trying to open my main.xml in eclipse

```
Error occurred during status handling
```

And I can't open the main.xml

Comment: I assume that's in Eclipse? Can you specify your Eclipse IDE version, if you have ADT installed, also version number.

Answer (score 0):

maybe close Eclipse => Open Eclipse ?

Comment: it is only in 1 layout? if not you must enter an administrator eclipse. And adt installed?